# 08006 idea-key-store KeyStore not available

Tags: intellij-idea, datagrip

After upgrading to Intellij 2023.2, I can no longer execute queries against any PostgreSQL database using the `Database Tools and SQL` plugin bundled with Ultimate edition. Executing any SQL results in the following error:

```
[08006] The SSLSocketFactory class provided com.intellij.execution.rmi.ssl.DefaultSslSocketFactory could not be instantiated.
idea-key-store KeyStore not available
```

Looking at the debug logs doesn't provide much more information than this.

```
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: idea-key-store KeyStore not available
    at java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
    at java.base/java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:676)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.java:868)
    ... 37 more
```

I *can* query Oracle databases, oddly.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As suggests by [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-18484) YouTrack issue, you can work around the error by setting

```
-DsslDeferredKeyLoading=true
```

in the VM options in the "advanced" tab of the data source settings.
That fixed the issue for me

Comment: Amazing, presumably there will eventually be a fix for this,